# Multiple dependency promise chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, extendscript, ecmascript-3

I'm trying to implement the following use case:

1. I've a sequence of sync tasks
2. Each sync task need to trigger an async task
3. Async tasks cannot run concurrently, so each one wait both for its trigger (2) and the completion of its predecessor.

[image]

My first idea was to convert every task (sync & async) into a promise then create two promise chains.
But I'm struggling finding a way to implement the async tasks chain with double dependency.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: I know about Promise.all but I don't understand how it will handle such case

Comment: Promise.all won't help in this situation... sounds like OP needs a next() methods to stick at the bottom of his then()s...

Comment: Actually I can't use es6 syntax since I'm using polyfill within es3 environment (adobe extendscript)

Comment: The premise of this question doesn't make any sense. JavaScript does not have preemptive multitasking, so there is no way for synchronous tasks to observably outlast asynchronous ones, because asynchronous completion can happen no sooner than at the end of the current run-to-completion of the event loop (after all synchronous code has finished).

Comment: @jib: Don't forget that not all EcmaScript implementations use the same concurrency model (which the spec doesn't detail at all). There are implementations with multithreading as well.

Comment: @Bergi, sure, but other threads cannot observably preempt the JavaScript singlethreading model. That means guaranteeing that `.then` callbacks not run before the end of the current run, or everything falls apart, and we need locks and semaphores.

Comment: @jib: Yes, I mean exactly this "everything falls apart" scenario, where promises would still be of great help. You just have to avoid mutating shared memory.

Comment: @Bergi `.then` callbacks typically share closures, and are also specified to "queue a microtask" which in my mind rules out concurrency on the closure, right? Same reason we have `await` in es7 async functions http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/

Comment: try: npm i task-chain
here is doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/task-chain

Answer (score 2):

Actually if your "sync tasks" are really synchronous, you can simply run them synchronously before starting your chain of asynchronous tasks and the condition that every "async task" runs after its respective "sync task" is trivially met, because all async tasks run after all sync tasks.

If your "sync tasks" are actually asynchronous themselves, or somehow run really parallel to each other (I don't know about the threading/concurrency model of ExtendScript), you should make each of the tasks (whether "sync" or "async") return a promise.

You can then build your <s>chain</s> network (acyclic graph) of dependencies using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var syncResult1 = syncTask1();
var asyncResult1 = syncResult1.then(asyncTask1);
var syncResult2 = syncResult1.then(syncTask2);
var asyncResult2 = Promise.all([asyncResult1, syncResult2]).then(asyncTask2);
var syncResult3 = syncResult2.then(syncTask3);
var asyncResult3 = Promise.all([asyncResult2, syncResult3]).then(asyncTask3);
```

(If your "sync tasks" don't need to return promises, just make it `syncResult… = syncTask…(syncResult…)`)

Answer (score 0):

You only need one promise chain:

```
syncTask1();
var promise1 = asyncTask1(); // Triggers first async task
syncTask2();
var promise2 = promise1.then( asyncTask2 );
syncTask3();
var promise3 = promise2.then( asyncTask3 );
...
```

Of course you would want to name your tasks and promises meaningfully. This will behave identically to this though, since JavaScript is single threaded and all the sync tasks will complete before the promise of asyncTask1 can resolve:

```
syncTask1();
var promise1 = asyncTask1(); // Triggers first async task
syncTask2();
syncTask3();
...
var promise2 = promise1.then( asyncTask2 );
var promise3 = promise2.then( asyncTask3 );
...
```

Comment: But with this implementation each asynctask is triggered only by previous asynctask.

Comment: @ChristopherCourtois Yes that's true, but node.js is single threaded so sync tasks cannot be interrupted anyway. If your sync tasks are quick that shouldn't be a problem. If they are long-running maybe they shouldn't be synchronous.

Comment: As you can see in the [flow illustration] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/pMJiV.png) sync tasks can take more time than async ones

Comment: In fact I run this javascript code within Adobe ExtendScript environment, sync tasks are InDesign export tasks and async tasks are Photoshop import tasks

Comment: @ChristopherCourtois The only way you would be able to have a diagram like that realized would be if you trigger the synchronous tasks asynchronously instead, so that the event loop has an opportunity to resolve promises and start the other async tasks too.

Comment: @ChristopherCourtois I don't know that environment, but you can make a sync flow return to the event loop by making use of `setTimeout` EG. `function triggerSyncTask1 ( ) { setTimeout( function ( ) { syncTask1(); triggerSyncTask2(); }, 0 ); }` That `setTimeout` causes the event loop to have a chance to execute anything that is already queued up before starting `syncTask1()`. In this case that would be more useful around `syncTask2();` when it gives the event loop the opportunity to resolve the promise and start `asyncTask2` before starting the sync task.

Comment: Ok but how this will help specifying that asyncTask2 depends on both completion of syncTask1 & aSyncTask1 ?

Comment: @ChristopherCourtois You would do `promise1.then( asyncTask2 )` in the same place where you call trigger `triggerSyncTask2()`, which is right after `syncTask1` completes.

Comment: Ok I got the idea here, need to test.

Answer (score 0):

From the diagram it looks like  Async2 and 3 depend on more than just fullfillment of the relative Sync function,

Using your naming conventions this is how I'd chain the promises:

```
               Synctask1
               |       |
             Sync2    Async1
             |     \     |
           Sync3    Async2(resolved with promiseAll[Async1, Sync2]
                \     |
                 \    |
                 Async3(resolved with promiseAll[Async2, Sync3]
```

Comment: Could you give me a snippet showing how you will chain Sync1, Sync2, Async1 & Async2 ?

Comment: How do I both run Sync2 & reference it in PromiseAll for Async2 ?